# How to change the color of the Android scroll bumper

Tags: android, codenameone

I created a Codename One project starting with the flatBlue theme, and then modified the theme to use my preferred color. I was able to change all colors I wanted, but I do not know how to change the color of the Android 'scroll bumper' that appears on the top (or bottom) of a component when scrolling. This 'scroll bumper' is blue, which suggests it comes from the flatBlue theme. How can I change the color of this 'scroll bumper' to match my modified theme colors?

Furthermore, I would like to know whether there are other parameters of this 'scroll bumper' that can be modified, e.g. can it be made larger or can it be disabled?

Kind regards, Frans.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a theme constant image which you can define via the theme constants `tensileHighlightTopImage` & `tensileHighlightBottomImage`.

Attached here for your convenience, top:

[image]

And Bottom:

[image]

Comment: This works fine, but in the end I decided to set the theme constant `tensileHighlightBool`to `false`, since I like that tensile effect better and this way I didn't have to create new images.