# Change the color of Android tensileHighlightTopImage & tensileHighlightBottomImage

Tags: codenameone

Having read the question and answers in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53758766/how-to-change-the-color-of-the-android-scroll-bumper) post , I don't quite understand how to go about manipulating the "tensile Highlight Image". Can anyone give an example of how I can work with these constants and change the color to one that I prefer?

Comment: What specifically are you trying to manipulate? Changes go in the `#Constants` CSS section. Notice that changes to that section don't update "live". You need to restart the simulator to see the impact.

Comment: I'm trying to change the "color" of the tensile Highlight Top and Bottom image color. Right now at the end of scrolling it appears as a blue line, which I believe matches the default Bare-Bones application.

Comment: These are images. You would need to get different images and replace them. You can download the android native theme and look at the values of the constants using the resource editor: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/tree/master/Themes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set constants `tensileHighlightBool` and `tensileDragBool` both to `false`, which works for me as it removes the tensile drag effect and the "blue" tensile highlight image, which doesn't blend with the theme of my app.